# ApexCharts y: 0 -> Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: vue.js, apexcharts

I'm using ApexCharts with vue3 (Composition API). I try to set the series dynamically via a reactive variable. Everything works fine until a dataset is empty - in the sense of its values being 0.

This is the general stub:

```
<template>
...
<apexchart width="100%" height="400" type="bar" :options="orderOptions" :series="orderSeries" ref="orderChart"></apexchart>
...
</template>


<script setup>
...
const orderSeries = ref([
  {
    name: 'Orders',
    data: []
  }
]);

const orderOptions = ref({
  xaxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  yaxis: {
    min: 0,
    labels: {
      formatter: val => val.toFixed(0)
    }
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  markers: {
    size: 7,
    hover: {
      size: 10
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      borderRadius: 4,
      borderRadiusApplication: 'end',
      columnWidth: '90%'
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Orders',
    style: {
      fontSize: '20px'
    }
  }
});
...
</script>
```

This works fine:

```
orderSeries.value[0].data = [{ x: '2022-03', y: 2 }]
```

But this:

```
orderSeries.value[0].data = [{ x: '2022-03', y: 0 }]
```

Gives me following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at s2 (apexcharts.common.js:10:11991)
    ...
```

As long as there is at least one element with a y value different than 0, it will work, but as soon as all y-values are 0, it throws this error.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with that code?

Comment: I found out that it might have to do something with min: 0 in orderOptions.yaxis. Removing that line will result in avoiding the error.